# bootstrap.min.css file not Supporting

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing  website, In the website there is 2 images and both images i am getting vertically but i need both images horizontally with animate. I am using bootstrap  for taking the images horizontally  but whenever i am inserting the bootstrap plugin (bootstrap.min.css) in  the file my  both images automatically hide.Please help me in this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Scroll effects with CSS animation</title>
<meta name="description" content="Page scroll animation using CSS animate" />  
<meta name="keywords" content="css animation, loading effect, animate, scroll loading, scroll animation" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />




<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


</head>

<body>

 <section class="hero overlay" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">

  </section>

<section class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <h2> Sport</h2>
      <p>Subheading Subheading Subheading</p>
      </br></br>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </br>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="post">
  <div class="box " >

      <img src="img/section1.jpg" alt="" style="height:300px;width:400px; ">
      <h4>Learn to sail Camps & Events at H20</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>

    </div>  </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="post2">

  <div class="box">
      <img src="img/section2.jpg" alt="" style="height:300px;width:400px;">
      <h4> My First Sailing Experience</h4>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </br>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
</section>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="viewportchecker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
      classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInLeft', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
      offset: 100    
     });   
});     

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post2').addClass("hidden1").viewportChecker({
      classToAdd: 'visible animated slideInRight', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
      offset: 100    
     });   
});     

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check for errors in console?

Comment: you have to include bootstrap, not just the theme css - I presume anyway

Comment: Thanks for reply , I am not getting any error.

Comment: Thanks for reply AleshaOleg , whenever i am inserting my bootstrap.min.css file at that time my image automatically hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use other class name instead of 'hidden' in the script. After the animation 'hidden' class is getting added to `<div class="post">` due to which the element is getting hidden after applying bootstrap.min.css

Comment: thanks for reply Mr.Onkar, i changed the hidden name and my issue is resolved 85% but  now issue is images are not in center. Please help me in this also

Comment: you can add shadow property to <img> element instead of <div class="box"> and add CSS property text-align:center to .box in style.css. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Onkar  i checked on local my issue re resolved now......Thanks for help.. I am really appreciate for every on

Answer (score 0):

Just you this `<link>`: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Load your bootstrap css first and then your other styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before you bootstrap.min.js call?

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the source of your site you can see that bootstrap.min.css isn't loading at all. Look at at your code, you forgot to add some close-bracket to your link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Try to change it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
```

Also I would suggest to load your bootstrap.css first and after that add your own .css files.

Comment: no, he talk about bootstrap.min.css, but the follow also true

Comment: I am getting issue in bootstrap.min.css not on font-asesome

Comment: These are protocol-relative URLs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Protocol-relative_URLs) and are fine to use, though HTTPS is preferred.

Comment: Updated my answer to help you further.